# c++ char display only ascii value?

Tags: c++, string, char, ascii

I want to build int array from string. However my issue is that it takes string or char as ascii, not its value.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int *arr = new int[10];
int j = 0;
string answer;
cout << "Enter the value: ";
// (4,3,1,2) is typed
cin >> answer;

void buildArr(string s){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        if(s[i] != '(' || s[i] != ',' || s[i] != ')'){
            arr[j] = (int)s[i];
            j++;
        }
   }
}
```

It supposed to make `arr` holds `4 3 1 2`. but it contains `40 52 44 51 44 49 44 50 41` which is same as `(4,3,1,2)`.

It takes `(` as 40 which is ascii number, it does not recognize it as '('. So my `if` statement does not filter out `(  , )` this three characters. How can I properly compare char?

I searched through other questions, and tried `s[i]-=0` but did not have any luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if anything it's `s[i]-='0'` (note the quotation marks), but basically just `arr[j] = s[i] - '0';`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code as provided cannot compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this:

```
if(s[i] != '(' || s[i] != ',' || s[i] != ')')
```

should be

```
if(s[i] != '(' && s[i] != ',' && s[i] != ')')
```

The way you had it, as `s[i]` can't ever be both `'('` and `','`, it will always evaluate to true.

Secondly,

```
arr[j] = (int)s[i];
```

should be

```
 arr[j] = s[i] - '0'
```

If you just cast it to an int, then you'll get the ascii value. To convert it to the actual number, subtract the ascii value of zero. In ascii, the numbers are all sequential, so if you subtract the ascii value for zero you get the offset in that list. There's a table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Didn't think my `if` condition was bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use and (`&&`) instead of or (`||`)
2. You need to convert ASCII values into integers, instead of `(int)s[i]` you can use `s[i] - '0'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
(int)str[i] - '0';
```

This will give you 4 instead of 40, etc.

Comment: `4` should have ASCII value `52`, `40` is `(` (what I mean to say is that this is not the full solution)

Comment: Correct, ascii value for 0 is 48 and 4 is 52 so 52-48 = 4.